# Roll a single 6 faced dice as many times as you want to reach a sum X

Tags: combinatorics, dice

I am working on a problem where a single dice with 6 face is rolled multiple times to reach a sum of X. This is a combinatorics problem. For example if I just want to find out the number of way a sum of 5 has to be obtained (not including negative numbers) the answer would be `(2^4) = 16`. Basically it follows the formula `2^(X-1)` where `X` is the sum. 

But the above formula is valid when there are the restrictions on the numbers that can be used. In my specific case I have the restriction of a six faced dice (numbers from 1 to 6). 
What should be my approach to solve this problem?

Comment: So one way to get a sum of 5 is to roll a 1 five times, 11111? Another way is a 2 and three 1's, 2111? Is 1211 different or the same?

Comment: @Arby They are different. Because sequence matters here

Comment: Do you only consider proper sums of 2 or more summands (e.g., 1+1=2), or do you consider "vacuous" sums of just 1 roll (e.g., roll a 2)?

Comment: @Xoque55 : Both are considered

Comment: So for a sum of 7, you get $2^7-1$ ways as a single roll of 7 is impossible. For 8, a single roll of 8 is impossible, as are rolls with 7 and 1 of which there are two giving $2^8-3$ ways. For 9, you can't have 9, 81, 18, 711, 171, 117, 72, nor 27, giving $2^9-8$ ways. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Arby : Hey, I am sorry. I did not add the brackets. The actual formula is 2^(X-1) not 2^X -1. Have edited the question too

Comment: But you see the technique I'm using, right? Sure looks like a pattern will show itself when you compute a few more.

Comment: @Arby : I don't quite understand your question?

Comment: @Arby : True that for 9  you can't have 81,711...but you can have 5211

Comment: Ok, the first time you get some effect is when the sum is 7, as no die has a face of 7. Thus you subtract 1 from your total. Next, went the sum is 8, you can't have 8, 71, nor 17, so subtract 3. How much you subtract follows a pattern as the sum increases, if you can find it, you can find your formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56898/discussion-between-arby-and-ashwin).

Comment: Short answer is these are the [hexanacci numbers](http://oeis.org/A001592) just slightly offset, with seed values $0,0,0,0,0,1$

Answer (score 1):

The generating function for the sum of $n$ rolls is $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^n$ so you can sum the coefficient of $x^X$ in this from $\lceil \frac X6 \rceil$ to $X$. Doing this in Excel is pretty quick if you want a numeric answer.  I find the series to be $$1,2,4,8,16,32,63,125,248,492,976,1936,3840,7617,15109,29970,59448,117920,233904,463968,920319,1825529,3621088,7182728,14247536,28261168,56058368,111196417,220567305,437513522,867844316,\ldots$$
These are the Hexanacci numbers, series [A001592 in OIES](http://oeis.org/A001592) where it says you can get the numbers (with an offset) as coefficients of $\frac {x^5}{1-x-x^2-x^3-x^4-x^5-x^6}$

Comment: For small $n$, the generating function approach would be fine, surely, but it runs in what, $O(n^2)$ time and a lot of memory storage?  Recurrence relations should yield the answer in just $O(n)$ time with minimal memory needed.

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I just found the OEIS link and the overall generating function, which seems like it should run in $O(n)$ time